# How I can calculate this product

Tags: real-analysis, products, real-numbers

How I can calculate this product:

$$s=∏_{j=1}^{p-3}\sinh^2[2^{j-1}\cosh^{-1}( 2)]$$ for a natural number $p>3$.

Comment: These are all integers (!)

Comment: @vadim123: Yes, all of them